Poker related. Probabilities of hitting Bad Beat Jackpot in 4card PLO and calculation of expected value based on that.
I'm George. And I have some headache you may help me solve. I hope.
As a poker professional poker player, I find myself playing jackpot games. That consists of the room taking a fee. Which happens to be a significant amount of money. And you get the fee back when you hit a concrete combination of cards and win or lose against another really are combination. That really are Situation makes a bad beat jackpot. Later I'l explain that in detail.
As a poker player, I usually play following a guideline made by a solver program which tells me what is the expected value of a given hand based on a rake structure (rake is the fee the room collects for playing every hand). But this simulation doesn't have in mind the extra fee for the Bad Beat Jackpot (BBJ from now on). So it's a mistaken simulation because of that.
Anyway, the EV of a given hand is different from the one of my simulation based on the probability of hitting this BBJ or not.
Making it so that hands that will never hit a Poker of $22$ or better ($\text{33-AA}$ or straightflush which is $5$ cards of the same suit next to each other) lose a big proportion of their EV to this BBJ fee.
Also, hands that are the most likely to hit the BBJ gain a significant amount of EV(expected value).
My question is regarding how much higher EV $22$ has compared to $\text{33-AA}$ and every straight flush combination) based on the probability it has of hitting a BBJ pot (where it hits $4$ of a kind and loses against a better combination of cards)
Based on this result I could do a better adaptation when choosing which cards to play which would give me an advantage over my competition.
I'm bad at mathematics, something I plan on fixing soon. So I'm sorry if the formulation of my question is less than optimal but I will be happy to answer your questions to fill in the gaps.
The basic info I have for this situation is next.

In 4card Pot Limit Omaha (the game I play) we are dealt $4$ cards in our hand and we need to make a combination of $2$ of them and $3$ of the table to hit a poker or a straight-flush in order to hit BBJ.

The cares on the table are used by all players tombine with the best $2$ of the $4$ they have hidden in their hands in order to make the strongest posible combination.
Those $4$ cards can be any combination between $2$ and $\text{A}$ in a standard French poker deck used for popular poker games. $2222, \ 2223$ and so on...

After different betting rounds $5$ other cards are dealt on the board. $3$ on the beginning of the hand. After a bet round, another one will be dealt if we don't fold before that. And after another betting round, there is a $5$-th card that we may see if we get there.

2.1 In my sample of $645767$ hands I've seen the flop (first $3$ cards) a total of $124667$ times. $19,305\%$ of the dealt hands.
2.2 I've seen the turn (fourth card) a total of $83273$ times.
2.3 I've seen the river a total of $56085$ times.
2.4 If you hit $3$ of a kind on the flop you will very rarely not see the turn and river. So when that happens the probability of seeing more cards is much higher than the stats on 2.1-2.3 points.

The Bad Beat Jackpot fee in a sample of the normal stake I play $250640$ hands I played is $201130 \ \$$. The average number of players in those tables of $5.23$.

So assuming that every player plays the same amount of hands, which is kinda of wrong since some players play way more than the professionals, It would mean that every player paid $38456 \ \$$ in this sample.
That is $15,3445 \ \$$ per $100$ hands.
In poker terms that would equal $3.0689\text{bb}/100 \text{BB}$ standing for Big Blind. Which is a way to translate the results to any other stakes. For example, if we played Big Blinds for $10 \ \$$ the same result would be easy to translate. So if you wish we can speak about EV in blinds instead of $\$$.

Bad Beat Jackpot winner rules.

$1$ player on the table must hit a poker of $2222$ or better hand (straight flush included) and lose against an even stronger combination from another player.
To do that both players MUST use $2$ cards from the $4$ they have at the beginning and $3$ others from the $5$ on the table. So if you have $22$ and on the table is $22$ it would be good.
But if you have an $\text{A2}$ and there is $222$ on the table, it won't be good. It's a poker by PLO rules, but not a good one for the BBJ prize.
Here we go with another example of a BBJ scenario.
If cards on the table are $\text{QhJhThTs2d}$, $\text{h}$ being hearts, $\text{s}$ being spades, $\text{d}$ being diamonds, $\text{c}$ for clubs, $\text{K}$ being a King, $\text{Q}$ being a Queen, $\text{J}$ being a Jack and $\text{T}$ being a Ten, 2 players could hit the BBJ in different ways.
Player 1 has $\text{TdTc}$ and Player 2 has a straight flush ($\text{AhKh, Kh9h, 9h8h}$) all $3$ would work.
Example 2. Player 1 has a lower straight flush and player 2 has a better one. $\text{8h9h}$ vs $\text{AhKh}$.
4.1 Prize:
A jackpot pool is recolected by the fees we pay. $\text{1BB}$ is recolected from every POT which is $\text{30bb}$ or larger.
In my database, the jackpot fees are an average of $ 15,3445 \ \$$ per $100$ hands in my stake. In this stake, the total pool right now is $290698 \ \$$, but it's usually a bit higher. $300000 \ \$$ or so.
When a BBJ is hit, the prizes are distributed between the players on the table.
The losing player (the worst combination of both) takes $10\%$ of the BBJ pool.
The winning player (best combo) earns $3\%$ of the pool.
The rest of the players just sitting on that table earn $0.80\%$ of the BBJ pool each.
So if we put the next starting hands as an example:
$$\text{2h2s3h3s, AhKhJsTd, AhJs8c4d}.$$
The best combination for hitting this BBJ would be $\text{2h2h3s3s}$ since it can hit $4$ kinds of losing or winning combinations. Being straight flush of hearts, spades, and poker of $2222$ and $3333$. So it can be the BBJ winner or loser in many different scenarios.
$\text{AhKh5s3d}$ could only hit a winning combination $\text{AhKhQhJhTh}$. So it would get a smaller prize of $3\%$ of the pool in only one scenario $\text{QhJ.hTh}$
And $\text{AhJs8d4c}$ can never win a jackpot so it only pays a fee and never recovers. Which makes it lose EV compared to the simulation I had initially.
So if $\text{AhJs8d4c}$ would be a 0,00EV play. Now it would become a losing hand since it loses the BBJ fee which never recovers.
And if $\text{2s2h3s3h}$ was a 0,00EV play now it becomes a big winner. But by how much?
That is my question for you guys. Do you think you can make a proper calculation regards this? To be able to add the different BBJ components of a hand and estimate the BBJ EV it has. Based on that, is it $+$EV or $-$EV? And by how much?
PD: I've seen a study about this topic focused on the Texas Hold'em game. In which you receive $2$ cards and $5$ are dealt on the table. Maybe it can be of use to you guys to find an example of what we try to do. This study may put some basic idea but it doesn't enter into the EV of concrete combinations of hole cards.
https://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/25/probability/what-point-does-bad-beat-jackpot-become-ev-961733/
http://people.math.sfu.ca/~alspach/comp46.pdf
I hope it can be of use to you guys. Thank you for your attention and I will answer anything needed to clarify the situation.
Cheers!

I've been thinking about simplification.
The basic question is what BBJ EV 22 has and how much more likely is 22 to hit BBJ than 33,44 and so on.
Then we translate that into EV terms and the question is done.
I also think that 99 may have more ways of hitting the jackpot than 22 because if the flop is 9h9s8s there are many straightforward ways for someone to hit a straight flush on the next 2 cards.
If the flop is 2h2s3s there are fewer ways. Also, people tend to play higher cards more often than low ones so high straight flushes are more likely to happen in a real game.

Also finding the half way threshold where a hand doesn't benefit from the BBJ but doesn't lose either is an important point. And how much some worse BBJ hands are losing to the BBJ fee of course.

Hi guys, If this is interesting to you I will add some info I've been thinking about to hack the BBJ structure.


BBJ may be cheaper and easier to hit in pots against various players. Since 1BB is paid if the pot becomes higher than 30bb. But Probability of a crush of strong hands is bigger since more cards are in play. So the EV of hunting the BBJ there becomes much higher. Most scenarios are 1v1 but some are 3 or 4way so there is a high EV spot


Playing smaller in scenarios where it doesn't hurt the EV of my hand. To reduce the pot average size and avoid 30bb+ scenarios more often.


